# Add custom notification when add & edit product in woocommerce admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to display my custom notification in woocommerce product add page above the Product name.

Review below screen. Below marked section I need to show custom message.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below code

```
function general_admin_notice() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ($pagenow == 'post-new.php' || $pagenow == 'edit.php' || $pagenow == 'post.php') {
        if ('product' === get_post_type($_GET['post'])) {
            echo '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible">
            <p>This notice appears on the settings page.</p>
            </div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'general_admin_notice');
```

Comment: Hi Aki, It's working fine. but it's display above the page. I need to show above the tile text box.  it's possible ?

Comment: Sorry Kane, I do not think so it is possible. Because by standard way there is no hook or filter for the title position as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

```
function filter_post_updated_messages( $message ) { 
  /***
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($message['product']);
  echo '</pre>'; 
  ***/

  $publish_msg = $message['product'][6];
  $publish_msg = str_replace('Product published.', 'Hi Great your new product published.', $publish_msg);
  $message['product'][6] = $publish_msg;
  return $message; 
};          
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'filter_post_updated_messages', 30, 1 );
```